# iOS UIScrollView bounces back to the top

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xcode4.5

When i scroll using UIScrollView downwards and let go it won't stay where i scrolled down to it bounces back to the top

http://www.joules.name/ScreenShot2013-01-25at19.11.45.png

http://joules.name/ScreenShot2013-01-25at19.04.12.png

in ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController


{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scoller;

}

@end
```

and in ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    [scoller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scoller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


}

@end
```

Comment: interesting. I don't see the content hugging and compression properties in Xcode 4.5.2.

Comment: how come the scrollview height is 800 in the nib.. are you on an iPad?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you set the actual height of the scrollview to 800 in the nib file. Change that to fit the screen.

Comment: It's iphone i have Changed the hight of the UIscrollview object to 504 size still don't Work (i thought you had to have the size off the UIscrollview object the same as the content and make sure   scoller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)]; is equal or larger than UIscrollview)